# .val().length: как правильно проверить наличие какого-то значения (текста) внутри блока?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно проверить наличие какого-то значения (текста) внутри блока.

Есть блоки div с классом `.product-wrapper` (таких блоков много), внутри этого блока, есть старая цена `.old-price`. Как сделать так: если у товара нет старой цены, к родителю `.product-wrapper` добавлялся бы новый класс, например `.new`?

Написал код, но он не работает:

```
    $('.product-wrapper').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.old-price').val().length) {
            $(this).parents('.product-wrapper').addClass("new");
        }
    });
```

Структура:

```
<div class="products-wrapper">

    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <div class="old-price">2500 руб.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <div class="old-price">старой цены нет, нужно проверить, что здесь пустота</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <div class="old-price">6750 руб.</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @jsp, Неплохо было бы глянуть на структуру HTML. И элемент с классом "old-price" - это элемент формы? Если наугад, то такой вариант:



    $('.product-wrapper').each(function () {
        if ($.trim( $(this).find('.old-price').val() ) == '') {
            $(this).closest('.product-wrapper').addClass("new");
        }
    });

Comment: Код не работает. Структура:

<div class="products-wrapper">

<div class="product-wrapper">
<div class="old-price">2500 руб.</div>
</div>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<div class="old-price">здесь старой цены нет</div>
</div>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<div class="old-price">6750 руб.</div>
</div>

<div class="product-wrapper">
<div class="old-price">здесь старой цены нет</div>
</div>

</div>

Comment: Супер! Все работает! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@jsp](/users/29115/jsp), это уже ближе к правде. Надеюсь, что "*здесь старой цены нет*" - это только для примера, в реальных условиях там пусто.

```
$('.old-price').each(function(i, el){
    if( $.trim( $(el).text() ) == '' ) {
       $(el).parent('.product-wrapper').addClass('new');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы явно не то написали, **$(this).find('.old-price').val().length** вернёт длину значения поля **.old-price**

А вам, насколько я понял, надо проверять наличие этих полей, точнее их отсутствие.

Значит вам надо использовать **!$(this).find('.old-price')** или **$(this).find('.old-price').length === 0**

То бишь вот такой примерно код должен работать:

```
$('.product-wrapper').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.old-price').length === 0) {
        $(this).parents('.product-wrapper').addClass("new");
    }
});
```

Comment: Не работает. Мне нужно проверить именно значение val, потому как в каждом .product-wrapper уже существует .old-price, но только когда есть старая цена у товара,  .old-price заполняется своим значением, вот это и нужно проверить, есть значение в .old-price или его нет.